# Is there any way to take values from tuple in list like dict?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am trying to take value from this list (tuple in list) below :

```
list =  [('look', 38),
         ('ganesh', 35),
         ('said', 30),
         ('tiger', 30),
         ('cat', 28)]
```

What I want to do is to take value with inputting word name, for instance if I input `'look'` then it will return `38` instead of inputting `list[0][1]` which I have already done. I have already eliminated all duplicated words in this list.
Otherwise, should I remake dictionary with separating items and values?

Comment: It looks like you want a dictionary.

Comment: past your list into the `dict` constructor: `d = dict(l)`. Note I renamed your list `l` because `list` is a type and you shouldn't use it as the name of a variable.

Comment: How can I make it from this list ?

Comment: No, you cannot make a list of tuples *act* like a dictionary without implementing, essentially, a dictionary. Instead, make your `list` of `tuple` s *into* a `dict`, i.e. `mydict = list(list_of_tuples)`

Comment: oh it was super easy...Thank you very much.

Comment: Looks like you want a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). You can easily construct this from your already existing data structure. Simply pass `list` into the dictionary constructor: `dict(list)`

Comment: Hy,
you're right .. if you want to access 38 by "look" use a dict object

    list =  {
    'look':38,
    ..
    }

list["look"] => 38

or if you cannot change your structure

    search = "look"
    for i in list:
      if list[0] == search: 
        found = list[1]
        break

Answer (score 2):

If the keys have no duplicates (if these have than the problem is rather ambiguous anyway), and the keys are *hashable* (strings are hashable), we can use a *dictionary*:

```
thelist = [('look', 38),
           ('ganesh', 35),
           ('said', 30),
           ('tiger', 30),
           ('cat', 28)]
thedict = dict(thelist)
```

Now we can perform a lookup with:

```
thedict['look']
```

This will give us `38`, in case we lookup a key that is not present, like `'bobcat'`, then Python will raise a key error:

```
>>> thedict['bobcat']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'bobcat
```

We can thus handle it with:

```
ourkey = 'bobcat'
try:
    ourvalue = thedict[ourkey]
except KeyError:
    # do something in case not present
    pass
```

> **Note**: do not use variable names like `list`, `dict`, `tuple`, etc. since you override references to the `list` class.
>
> **Note**: in case you want to use a default value instead when the lookup fails, you can use `thedict.get(ourkey, defaultvalue)`, or in case that should be `None`, we can use `thedict.get(ourkey)`. Note that if such function returns `None`, that does *not* per se means that the key was not found: it can mean that the key was not found, but it can also be the result of the fact that the key was associated with a `None` value.

Comment: One can also use the `get()` method of dictionary to safely return a sensible value if the key does not exist.

Comment: If `ourvalue` will simply be assigned another value in the `except` block, one could use `dict.get` (to return a default value).

Comment: @pault: yes, but my experience as a developer of production software is that it frequently does more harm than good, since one of the credos of Python is *you should never pass errors silently, unless these are silenced explicitly*. I've unfortunately seen a lot of trouble arising from `.get(..)` this is partly because if you do not pass an explicit default value, then it returns `None`, but `None` can be in the dictionary as well.

Comment: Thank you for answers, and yes I have already removed all duplicated keys.

Comment: Fair point- I only suggested it for the sake of completeness.